# google chrome's context menu colors

Tags: google-chrome, colors

Since the last google chrome update the context menu selection color changed to a color that is very similar to the same menu color. I can't see the selection well now. 
Is there any way of changing the colors of the selected item or the color of the menus in google chrome? 
I've made a search but can't find anything. I've tried a couple of themes too, but they seem to change many things but not the context menu colors or selection color.

[image: context menu]

Comment: Chrome stable still uses the system menus on Windows. What OS are you using? And which version of Chrome are you using? Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I use Windows 7 and chrome Version 26.0.1410.12 beta-m

Comment: I can't add images yet, I need a reputation of 10 at least :-( just answered a couple of questions let's see it that gives me any reputation

Comment: If you add the URL to the image, someone else is likely to put the actual image in for you :)

Comment: Which I've now done.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can start Chrome with parameter `-disable-new-menu-style`.

Comment: Could you provide some more details about how to do this? Must this be done from the command line?

Comment: This switch isn't working anymore.